# How to increase Spark log level - Shutdown Hook Called

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting this error and I was told I can increase log level of spark to investigate what's wrong. I am not sure how to do that. Please try to provide a step-by-step guide to that as I am very new to Spark.

[image]

So far I have tried to edit the log4j.properties file but I got "permission denied". I don't think the admin would allow me to edit it as well.

Below is the content of the step1.sh file I was trying to run:

[image]

Thank you for the help.

****Update:****

So I checked the yarn log of one of the applications that failed.
What does this indicate?
[image]

Comment: I don't see an error in that output. The "shutdown hook called" just means that it completed.

Comment: @jordanm so it means the step1.py in the bash script finished running successfully without a bug?

Comment: Doubtful just due to the amount of time. Yarn logs is likely what you want to look at, since it appears spark is submitting fine.

Comment: one question why are you using 500 executors ,  how much big is your cluster & the data you are loading ??

Comment: @jordanm how can I check that?

Comment: @Srinivas its a lot of data

Comment: @LLL even so, you are requesting 2000 CPU cores and 4000GB of memory.

Comment: @jordanm my team set it up so I was following what they have

Comment: May be you need to understand why they give that much memory.. and can you post how many nodes are there in your cluster ??

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions .  Can you post yarn logs.. shutdown hook will be called most of the cases.. if your app is complete success or failure..

Comment: @Srinivas I am trying to use "yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID>" to check. How do I find the application id?